# When do we not use definite article, "the"?

Tags: articles, style-manuals

I have a question. Could you please explain why “the” is not used in the parts that I have indicated in **bold**? Why is "the" missing?

> Little is known about the lives of early human beings. What we do know has been gathered through the study of ancient caves that scientists called archeologists believe **early humans** probably lived in.
>   The evidence suggests that the first human beings lived in **caves** along the southern coast of Africa. This region provided ample supplies of food as well as a warm climate.

The text above is from https://kidspast.com/world-history/prehistoric-humans/

Comment: I kinda suspect there's been a question on this before.  Maybe if you look under "RELATED" to the right you'll find something.

Comment: They use the null article because those references are ['more definite'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/427204/142322) than using the definite article would indicate.

Comment: @Lawrewnce Isn't 'caves' the zero article as very non-specific?

Comment: Related: [“You're missing the posts only available to members” — should there be a “the” in there?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73341/youre-missing-the-posts-only-available-to-members-should-there-be-a-the-i) and [Can anyone explain the use of determiners in this passage?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56712/can-anyone-explain-the-use-of-determiners-in-this-passage)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot say **the** because that would suggest that those were **the** only early humans, which is untrue. Caves would also be similar. Since the caves the article mentions are not the only caves in the world, the word **the** would be incorrect.